# Copy the area defined by mask into a new continuous image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I would like to copy the mask pixels (maybe non continuous) into a new image of size that of mask. I have outlined the objective I am trying to achieve via this image.

One way to achieve this would be to loop through the complete image, compare mask value (== 255) for the particular pixel and then copy that into the new image.

What I am interested in - is there a *better way* to accomplishing the same? Something more *optimized for performance*.

[image: Process from full color image to color Sub image]

```
 fullImage = cv::imread("full_image.png");
 cv::Mat grayImage;
 cv::cvtColor(fullImage, grayImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    
 threshold, dst = cv::threshold(grayImage, 10, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
 cv::Mat subImage (1, cv::countNonZero(threshold), CV_8UC3, Scalar(255, 255, 255));

 int siColIdx = 0;
 // now loop thru the image    
 for (int i=0; i < fullImage.rows; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < fullImage.cols; j++) {
       if (threshold.at<uchar>(i, j) == 255) {
           subImage[siColIdx++] = fullImage.at<uchar>(i, j);
       }
    }
 }
```

disclaimer: the code has not been tested. Purely to provide one approach to the solution.

Comment: **Have you profiled it?** Anyway, you can avoid the `threshold` and `countNonZero` functions: change the "if" condition inside the double loop with >10, and start with a subImage as big as grayImage. At the end you can crop the subImage with the actual number of pixels (you can keep track of the number of pixels with a counter inside the "if").

Comment: so you just want to lump those pixels together without maintaining shape? what for?

Comment: There shouldnt be any optimized function for that (maybe some kind of sorting, but might not ne optimal.) and your loop should be quite fast in release build. A bit of performance can be gained by row-pointer variable. However in your code there is a bug,you are copying uchar but your image pixels are cv::vec3b

Comment: @Miki - Those are great suggestions indeed. The if condition (which anyway needs to exist) can handle thresholding and countNonZero. The siColIdx is being used to keep count of pixels being covered.
Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - The idea is to run some averaging operation in the area of interest. I would not like the components outside the image to influence the average. While some operations do support mask based operation, many don't. 
I can of course reshape the image or just use as a continuous array. I don't think it may matter in most processing.

Comment: @Micka - You are right about uchar and cv:Vec3b, need to fix that. 
I don't think it will matter whether I run the loop using a single channel or 3.

Comment: @Miki - I haven't profile it but was trying to find if there was more optimized way than use of loops.

Comment: It makes a difference because fullImage is 3-channel and if you access it as 1-channel you will copy completely wrong values. But I understand that this isnt really part of the question.

Comment: Btw, both functions: mean and meanStdDv support masks: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga846c858f4004d59493d7c6a4354b301d if you have your own averaging I would guess performing it directly in the loop would bemote efficient, instead of first creating another Mat (which will even have pixels at the end of most rows which were not masked in the fullImage).

Comment: @Micka I am aware of the support for mask in mean & stddev. My requirement is to other operations like in frequency domain where it may be difficult to segment correct. In the sample image in my question, I would like to just explore properties of the background (sky) and understand the transformation in frequency domain.
Is there a way to do that with DFT/DCT/DWT? The color of the sky itself may be different (hue, saturation, etc.) so I can't pick segment it purely on that.